# Angular JS with Angular2

Tags: angularjs, angular

My Single page app is developed using AngularJS and deployed to Prod and it's working fine.

Now I need to add a new page/route in my webapp but i want to develop that page in Angular2 and don't want to upgrade my existing page to angular2.

Is it possible to do it and how?

Comment: Sorry, it cannot be done that way.

Comment: Even if you can it would be too heavy since you need to all the dependency for that again.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can have an Angular v1.x (AngularJS) and Angular v2+ (just Angular) app working together. Check out the ngUpgrade feature in the docs here: https://angular.io/guide/upgrade#upgrading-with-ngupgrade

From the docs:

> This is a module that contains utilities for bootstrapping and managing hybrid applications that support both Angular and AngularJS code.